# EntityFramework Core with one-to-many relation always returns an empty collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using an IEntityTypeConfiguration interface to configure the entities.
So, for example, I have 2 tables with names: Students / Courses.

There are configuration of tables:

**Courses**:

`builder.HasMany(x => x.Students).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.CourseId);`

**Students**:

`builder.HasOne(x => x.Course).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.CourseId);`

Next step is to create a test for ensure that the data is loaded correctly.
I have a repository that converts an entity to a model, but first I want to test it manually with my Context.

I have created a course and list of students, there are the students (EntityManager adds fake data to Context and save it), actually creates 100 entities by default:

```
var students = await EntityManager.CreateManyAsync<Student>(
                x => x.CourseId = course.Id);
```

Then I just search for course, include the Students and test it via FluentAssertions.

```
var set = TestDatabase.Context.Set<Course>();
var course = await set.Include(x => x.Students).FirstAsync(x => x.Id == course.Id);
course.Students.Should().NotBeEmpty();
```

Entity is here, but collection is empty (but not null, given that I did not initialize it).

For unit tests I'm use the actual Context and InMemoryDatabase.

Entity collection:

```
public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

What's wrong I do?

P.S. There are no errors in the EntityManager, the relation ids is set correctly.

Comment: 1) only one configuration is needed(either of them); 2) if you try to select Student and it's course(other direction), would it work?

Comment: @Uriil 2) Yep, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the relation from the Students table and changed WithOne() in the Course configuration to WithOne(x=>x.Course), and now it works completely. Thanks to @Uriil